# Training new font in tesseract 3.04

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to train new belarussian font in tesseract 3.04. I edited box files, made some traineddata files with dictionaries. Now I have traineddata, which do some correct recognition results, but not 80% quality at least. How can I improve recognition quality? I have multi tiff with 29 pages. Now I use this traineddata like  "-l bel+bel1"